# Router::parseExtensions() for only a specifc route

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to use Router::parseExtensions() for only one route?

I need the `xml` extension only for my `SitemapsController` but for no other routes. Using `Router::parseExtensions(array('xml'))` also serves the unwanted `/news/foo.xml` which equals `/news/foo` (duplicate content).

Answer (score 1):

If you need request something like this

```
http://localhost/sitemap.xml
```

Then add route:

```
Router::connect('/sitemap.xml', array('controller' => 'sitemaps', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Add beforeFilter() function to SitemapsController.php:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->viewClass = 'Xml';
}
```

If you don't want to set extension in route rule and want more complex solution, you have to set correct action:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->viewClass = 'Xml';
    $action = reset(explode(".", $this->request->params['action']));
    $this->setAction($action);
}
```